# Как запросить у пользователя массив из 10 строк и вывести на экран наименьшую

Tags: c++, массивы, вывод

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу на C++.

Запросить у пользователя массив из 10 строк и вывести на экран наименьшую

Пример моего кода(Он выводит последнее значение из масива. Я не знаю, как вывести наименьший массив из строки):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    const int str = 11;
    char s[str];

    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите строки:\n";
        cin >> s;
        cout << "Строка:  " << i << " - " << s << " Длина: " << strlen(s) << endl;
    }   
    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
    {
        cout << "Строка:  " << i << " - " << s << " Длина: " << strlen(s) << endl;

    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы что-нибудь, типа учебника по С++, читали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понимаю, почему вы создаёте массив всего из 11 символов, строчка может быть гораздо больше. И если вы введёте таковую у вас получится ошибка. Где вы вообще находите наименьшую по длине строчку? Вы просто вводите в одну и ту же строку последовательно 11 раз разные строчки и понятно, что программа запомнит последнюю только. Вы должны создать массив строк. Если писать код вашим стилем, то вот:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    const int maxsize = 100; //чтобы хватило, но опять же не факт, что хватит
    char arr[10][maxsize];  //создание массива на 10 строк

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите строку:\n";
        cin >> arr[i];
        cout << "Строка:  " << i << " - " << arr[i] << " Длина: " << strlen(arr[i]) << endl;
    }   
    int max_len = 0, max_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (max_len < strlen(arr[i])) {
            max_len = strlen(arr[i]);
            max_index = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "Строчка с максимальной длиной: " << arr[max_index] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Но я бы вообще не парился по поводу размеров строк и прочего и сделал всё с помощью `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    string arr[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) cin >> arr[i];
    int max_len = 0, max_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (arr[i].size() > max_len) {
            max_len = arr[i].size();
            max_index = i;
        }
    }
    cout << max_len;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, я разобрался.

Comment: Вы сначала вводите в массив, а потом начинаете разбирать элементы массива. Это совершенно ни к чему. Просто нужно  при самом вводе  сохранить нужные данные, и не нужен никакой массив.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan можно и без массива, для понятия написал таким же методом, который использовал автор вопроса